# How to check a variable is a string or a number in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm writing a program that adds the numbers of a list provided by the user, but, in case there is an string it gives me an error. How do I check if an element of the list is a string or a number?
Thanx

Answer (score 2):

`number/1` will tell you if an object is a number. `atom/1` will tell you if an object is an atom, which I presume is what you mean by a string. If you meant a true string (list of character codes), then

```
string(Object) :-
    forall(member(X, Object), number(X))
```

will do the trick.

All of these will fail in the presence of variables.

Comment: better naming, seen 'object' at begin of answer, could be:forall(member(X, List), number(X))

Comment: @chac: I don't completely grasp what you're saying, but the idea is that you apply the `forall` to the *elements of the list* that the OP refers to (because strings in Prolog are in fact lists themselves).

Comment: Effectively I didn't understood your clue, thanks for explaining.

Comment: @chac: clarified the answer (I hope).

Answer (score 0):

If your list contains strings that you want to read as numbers:

```
...maplist(convert_element, List, OnlyNumbers),

convert_element(Num, Num) :- number(Num).
convert_element(String, Num) :- number_codes(Num, String).
convert_element(Unknown, 0) :- throw(unknown(Unknown)).
```

`throw` could be replaced with a message...

Comment: The goal `convert_element(1,N)` succeds with `N = 1` but will ultimately produce the error `unknown(1)` upon failure. You want some conditional construct or negation to cover this.

Answer (score 0):

```
number(10.0). % true
string("hello"). % true
```

I don´t know why the other answers are so complicated...